# Remap escape key to underscore

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I'm currently working on remapping my keyboard using PCkeyboardhack for MAC OSX.

I'm currently looking for the virtual key for underscore. Is the only way to get this key with the shift modifier key?

I was trying to remap my escape key to underscore as I don't use the escape key. I frequently use underscore, but I cant find the virtual key anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

step 1: use Karabiner (formerly keyremap4mac) to change right shift to underscore

step 2: use PCKeyboardHack to change right shift to left shift

step 3: use PCKeyboardHack to change escape to right shift

step 4: use PCKeyboardHack to change capslock to escape.

escape = underscore

both shift keys = left shift

capslock = escape